# Can i restore the backup directly from pc . without enabling debud mode... or how can i fix the problem with black screen

Tags: backup, unbricking

my device is totally bricked after flashing stock rom with sp flash tool .. it start up with start sound but display show black everything else work well but display is the problem .. i have CWM backup of my own phone and i have scatter file too .. plzz is there any solution regarding my problem .. can i restore the backup directly from pc . without enabling debud mode... or how can i fix the problem with black display ... plzz healp me to solve ..

thank u.

Comment: Can you get into Recovery mode?  (Please put some effort into formatting and spelling, this is hard to understand.)

Answer (score 2):

You're probably going to need to specify *exactly* what model phone you have, because not all phones bootstrap the same way.

In *general*, however, if you can't get the phone to go into it's equivalent of Download/Odin mode (where it simply doesn't do anything except listen over USB for an upload of a firmware file) with the majority of the phones on the market, you're *done*.  There's pretty much nothing else to do that wouldn't require special hardware.